# Trying to write to a Google Sheet via gspread in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to write some data to a google sheet and keep getting this error.

File "anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyasn1_modules/rfc2459.py", line 1014, in AttributeTypeAndValue
    openType=opentype.OpenType('type', certificateAttributesMap))

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'openType'

I am using Gspread 2.2.1 in python 3.6.0. TextEditor is Spyder 2.7.

Here is my code.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Any help would be helpful.

```
  import gspread  
  from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

  scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
  creds = 
  ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
  client = gspread.authorize(creds)

  sheet = client.open("TEST").sheet1
  sheet.update_cell(1, 1, "I just wrote to a spreadsheet using Python!")
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should include relevant library versions.

Comment: I am using Gspread 2.2.1 in python 3.6.0.

Comment: That's not the latest release of gspread. Nor is it a listed official release. Upgrade.

Comment: What if it says package up to date?

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: gspread in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=2.2.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gspread)
Requirement already up-to-date: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.2.1->gspread)
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.2.1->gspread)

Comment: Then your configuration needs updating: https://github.com/burnash/gspread/releases